# How to set dynamic starting and ending date of the fiscal year in Python

Tags: python, bash

I am working in a python script which will deal with fiscal years and their respective reporting periods.
Having in mind that not every country (and this script will be used in multiple countries) do not have the same fiscal years, i need to make it dynamic.

What I seek is the case when the fiscal year doesn't start on the 1st of January but on a different date.
e.g.

*start date: 2020-04-01 (1st of April of 2020)*

*end date: 2021-03-31 (31st of March 2021)*

This is the code:

```
    start_month = self.data_handler.get_cell_value(excel_file, sheet, 'A2')
    start_day = self.data_handler.get_cell_value(excel_file, sheet, 'B2')
    end_month = self.data_handler.get_cell_value(excel_file, sheet, 'C2')
    end_day = self.data_handler.get_cell_value(excel_file, sheet, 'D2')
    
    for year_ in years:
        if start_day != 1 or start_month != 1 or end_day != 31 or end_month != 12:
            end_year = year_ + 1
        else:
            end_year = year_

        new_fiscal_year = {
            'code': str(year_),
            'date_start': str(year_) + "-" + str('%02d' % start_month) + "-" + str('%02d' % start_day),
            'date_stop': str(end_year) + "-" + str('%02d' % end_month) + "-" + str('%02d' % end_day),
            'name': str(year_),
        }
        self.openerpclient.create('account.fiscalyear', new_fiscal_year)
        current_fiscal_year = self.openerpclient.fetch('account.fiscalyear', [('code', 'like', str(year_))], ['id'])


        for month_ in range(1, 13):
            # last_day =  Since different months have different numbers of days, here we save the last day of the corresponding month
            last_day = calendar.monthrange(int(year_), month_)[1]
            first_day_of_the_month = datetime(year=int(year_), month=month_, day=1).date()
            last_day_of_the_month = datetime(year=int(year_), month=month_, day=last_day).date()

            new_periods = {
                'date_start': str(first_day_of_the_month),
                'date_stop': str(last_day_of_the_month),
                'fiscalyear_id': str(current_fiscal_year[0]['id']),
                'name': str('%02d' % month_ + "/" + str(year_)),
                'code': str('%02d' % month_ + "/" + str(year_)),
            }
             print("AA", new_periods)
            self.openerpclient.create('account.period', new_periods)
```

But this is not working as my expected output which would be:

```
AA {'date_start': '2020-04-01', 'date_stop': '2020-04-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '04/2020', 'code': '01/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-05-01', 'date_stop': '2020-05-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '05/2020', 'code': '02/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-06-01', 'date_stop': '2020-06-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '06/2020', 'code': '03/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-07-01', 'date_stop': '2020-07-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '07/2020', 'code': '04/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-08-01', 'date_stop': '2020-08-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '08/2020', 'code': '05/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-09-01', 'date_stop': '2020-09-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '09/2020', 'code': '06/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-10-01', 'date_stop': '2020-10-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '10/2020', 'code': '07/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-11-01', 'date_stop': '2020-11-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '11/2020', 'code': '08/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2020-12-01', 'date_stop': '2020-12-01', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '12/2020', 'code': '09/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2021-01-01', 'date_stop': '2021-01-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '01/2021', 'code': '10/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2021-02-01', 'date_stop': '2021-02-28', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '02/2021', 'code': '11/2020'}
AA {'date_start': '2021-03-01', 'date_stop': '2021-03-31', 'fiscalyear_id': '1', 'name': '03/2021', 'code': '12/2020'}
```

In a nutshell, I'd like my starting and ending dates to correspond with the year I'm working on, and move into the next year until the end date of that fiscal year.

Comment: What exactly must be your function inputs?

Comment: 12 month and 20 years

Comment: Start year? and also if I understand correctly, both the fiscal years will have 12 months right?

Comment: Start year it's current year. Yes, all of them have 12 months

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```py
import datetime as dt
import time

delta = dt.timedelta(days=365)


def fiscal_years(num_of_years, fiscal_year_type='J'):
    start_year = time.localtime().tm_year
    if fiscal_year_type == 'J':
        start_date = dt.date(start_year, 1, 1)
    elif fiscal_year_type == 'A':
        start_date = dt.date(start_year, 4, 1)
    for i in range(num_of_years):
        print {"start": str(start_date), "stop": str(start_date + delta)}
        start_date = start_date + delta


fiscal_years(5, 'A')
```

#### output

```
{'start': '2020-04-01', 'stop': '2021-04-01'}
{'start': '2021-04-01', 'stop': '2022-04-01'}
{'start': '2022-04-01', 'stop': '2023-04-01'}
{'start': '2023-04-01', 'stop': '2024-03-31'}
{'start': '2024-03-31', 'stop': '2025-03-31'}
```

There are some more finer details (leap year and fiscal year start being other than april and january) to handle but this should give you an idea